# SQL error on ID insert with EF in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am making a multi-page registration with session and adding to the database after so my actions are like

```
public IActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel registerViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (!_context.users.Any(u => u.Email == registerViewModel.User.Email))
        {
            User user = new User
                    {
                        firstName = registerViewModel.User.firstName,
                        ...
                    };
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("SessionUser", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));

            registerViewModel.gyms = _context.gyms.ToList();

            return View("~/Views/Account/Register2.cshtml", registerViewModel);
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "This Email is taken");
    }

    return View(registerViewModel);
}
```

It gets data from the form,saves it to session in json format then sends it to the 2nd and so on:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Register2(RegisterViewModel registerViewModel)
{
    if (registerViewModel.gym != null)
    {
        User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionUser"));
        user.gym = _context.gyms.Find(registerViewModel.gym.gymID);
        ....

        HttpContext.Session.SetString("SessionUser", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));

        RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel()
                {
                    User = user,
                    gym = user.gym
                };

        return View("~/Views/Account/Register3.cshtml", model);
    }
}
```

and if I do `context.Add(user);` and save changes here it works fine, but I get to the 3rd part which is

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Register3(RegisterViewModel registerViewModel)
{
    if (registerViewModel.User != null)
    {
        User user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionUser"));
        ...
        user.Token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        _context.Add(user);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        Response.Cookies.Append("token", user.Token, new CookieOptions
                {
                    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),
                    HttpOnly = true
                });

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
}
```

I get an error

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table gyms when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF, gyms is the DbSet gyms.

The way I found to avoid this error was to add the user to database on Register2, and update it again on Register3, but of works that causes a problem of adding the user in before finishing the registration,i read about the other similar questions with this error, it causes this error when gymID in added to database but could not find the correlation.

My user model is like this:

```
[Key]
[Required]
public int UserID { get; set; }

[Required]
[MaxLength(100)]
public String firstName { get; set; }
....

public Gym gym { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because of Entity Framework's tracking. Since you are deserializing the `User` object, its deserialized `Gym` object is being loaded (with the existing Id) but outside of Entity Framework's tracking. So, since Entity Framework isn't tracking it, it thinks you are trying to create a new `Gym` with an existing Id.

Try storing just the `Gym` Id on the `User` object you're serializing into session, instead of the entire `Gym` object.

Answer (score 0):

It was some relation error, fixed after re-declaring:

```
int gymId = user.gym.gymID;
user.gym = _context.gyms.Find(gymId);
```